# Proof of easy property of group

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a theorem 1.9 from Algebra by Hungerford:
If $G$ is a group and $g\in G$, then fo all $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
g^{m}g^{n}=g^{m+n},\\
(g^{m})^{n}=g^{mn}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

We need to prove in four cases: case $1$ is when $m,n>0$; case $2$ is when $m>0, n<0$; case $3$ is when $m<0, n>0$; case $4$ is when $m,n<0$. By showing $(g^n)^{-1}=(g^{-1})^{n}$, $g^{-n}=(g^{-1})^{n}$ and case $1$ holds we know case $4$ holds. However I don't know how to prove in case $2$ and $3$. How can I start?

Edit: when $m,n=0$, the statement holds trivially.

Comment: I, too, think that these four cases are not enough and there should be six, if you are following this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g \in G$. I assume that your definition of the powers of $g\in G$ is the following:

\begin{aligned}
g^0&:=e \\
g^{n+1}&:=g^ng \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ for every }n \in \mathbb{N}\\
g^{-n}&:= (g^n)^{-1} \,\,\,\,\text{ for every positive }n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{aligned}

where $e$ is the neutral element of $G$.

$(0)$ At first we prove by induction on $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that $g^{n+1}=g^ng=gg^n$.

If $n=0$ we are done.

If $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is such that $g^{n+1}=g^ng=gg^n$, then $g^{(n+1)+1}=g^{n+1}g=gg^ng=ggg^n=gg^{n+1}$.

$(1)$ We prove by induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the following holds: for every $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ it is the case that $g^mg^n=g^{m+n}$.

If $n=0$ then for every $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ it is the case that $g^mg^n=g^mg^0=g^me=g^m=g^{m+0}=g^{m+n}$.

If $n \in \mathbb{N}$ verifies that for every $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ it is the case that $g^mg^n=g^{mn}$, then: $$g^mg^{n+1}=g^mg^ng=(g^mg^n)g=g^{m+n}g=g^{(m+n)+1}=g^{m+(n+1)}.$$

So far we proved that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and every $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ it is the case that $g^mg^n=g^{m+n}$.

$(2)$ Now we prove by induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it is the case that $(g^n)^{-1}=(g^{-1})^n$.

If $n=0$ we are done.

If for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it is the case that $(g^n)^{-1}=(g^{-1})^n$, then: $$(g^{n+1})^{-1}=(g^ng)^{-1}=g^{-1}(g^{n})^{-1}=g^{-1}(g^{-1})^n=(g^{-1})^{n+1}$$ where the last equality holds by $(1)$.

$(3)$ Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then by $(2)$ it is the case that $(g^{-n})^{-1}=((g^n)^{-1})^{-1}=((g^{-1})^n)^{-1}=(g^{-1})^{-n}$. We proved that for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ it is the case that $(g^n)^{-1}=(g^{-1})^n$. Moreover observe that if $n <0$ then $g^{-n}=((g^{-n})^{-1})^{-1}=(g^n)^{-1}$. Hence we proved that, for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, it is the case that: $$g^{-n}=(g^{n})^{-1}=(g^{-1})^{n}.$$

$(4)$ Finally let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, for every $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ it is the case that $g^mg^{-n}=((g^{m})^{-1})^{-1}(g^{n})^{-1}=(g^{-m})^{-1}(g^{n})^{-1}=(g^{-1})^{-m}(g^{-1})^n=(g^{-1})^{-m+n}=g^{m-n}$. Hence we proved that, for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and every $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ it is the case that $g^{m}g^{ n}=g^{m+n}$.

For the other equality, follow the same steps.

Comment: Your proof of (1) relies on having $g^p g = g^{p+1}$ for all $p$. Is this obvious with your definition?

Comment: Well, my definition only ensures this for $p \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: But you apply this to $p=m+n$ in your proof of (1), and this $p$ can be negative.

Comment: ah you're right

Comment: then I think the best choice is to prove that for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the formula holds and generalize both $m$ and $n$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ in part $(4)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $m>0$ and $n<0$ and assume that $m>-n$. We have by the first case:
$$g^m=g^{m+n+(-n)}=g^{m+n}g^{-n}.$$
Then $g^m g^n=g^{m+n}$. The other cases will be treated in similar way.